# Convert multiple rows in to single row in SQL using Case-When

Tags: sql, oracle

What I want to do is to convert multiple rows into a single row using case-when, but I get

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

this is my query

```
SELECT  P.APPDISPLAYNAME AS PLAYERNAME ,
        CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 1 THEN SS.SETSCORE END AS set1,
        CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 2 THEN SS.SETSCORE END AS set2,
        CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 3 THEN SS.SETSCORE END AS set3,
        CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 4 THEN SS.SETSCORE END AS set4
FROM    TENNISMATCH TM ,
        TEAM T ,
        TEAMPLAYER TP ,
        TOURNAMENTPLAYER TRP ,
        PLAYER P ,
        SETSCORE SS ,
        GAMESET GS ,
        PLAYERBIO PB
WHERE   TM.EVENTTYPE = 'MEN_SINGLES'
        AND TM.MATCHSTATUS = 'LIVE'
        AND TM.TENNISMATCHID = T.TENNISMATCHID
        AND T.TEAMID = TP.TEAMID
        AND TP.TOURNAMENTPLAYERID = TRP.TOURNAMENTPLAYERID
        AND TRP.PLAYERID = P.PLAYERID
        AND T.TEAMID = SS.TEAMID
        AND SS.GAMESETID = GS.GAMESETID
        AND P.PLAYERID = PB.PLAYERID
GROUP BY P.APPDISPLAYNAME
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Even Oracle now recommends its use.

Second, your `SELECT` needs aggregation functions.  I would recommend something like this:

```
SELECT  P.APPDISPLAYNAME AS PLAYERNAME ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 1 THEN SS.SETSCORE END) AS set1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 2 THEN SS.SETSCORE END) AS set2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 3 THEN SS.SETSCORE END) AS set3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER = 4 THEN SS.SETSCORE END) AS set4
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

All the columns that appear in your `SELECT` clause must either be included in your `GROUP BY` clause, or else have some kind of [Aggregate function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) applied.

In your case, if you want just one row to be returned, you should for example use a `MAX()` function applied to every one of your `CASE` results.

This will of course not be accurate if the `CASE` statements can return different results for each row. But if that's the case, then your problem cannot be solved.

Try adding this to every `CASE`:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER=1 THEN SS.SETSCORE END) as set1
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. It worked with aggregate functions.                                        Below is the modified query: SELECT MATCHID, PLAYERNAME, SUM(set1), SUM(set2), SUM(set3), SUM(set4) FROM (SELECT TM.TENNISMATCHID AS MATCHID, P.APPDISPLAYNAME as PLAYERNAME, CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER=1 THEN SS.SETSCORE ELSE 0 END as set1, CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER=2 THEN SS.SETSCORE ELSE 0 end as set2,
CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER=3 THEN SS.SETSCORE ELSE 0 end as set3, CASE WHEN GS.SETNUMBER=4 THEN SS.SETSCORE ELSE 0 end as set4

Comment: query contd...from TENNISMATCH TM, TEAM T, TEAMPLAYER TP, TOURNAMENTPLAYER TRP, 
PLAYER P, SETSCORE SS, GAMESET GS, PLAYERBIO PB
WHERE TM.MATCHSTATUS='LIVE' AND TM.TENNISMATCHID=T.TENNISMATCHID AND T.TEAMID=TP.TEAMID AND 
TP.TOURNAMENTPLAYERID=TRP.TOURNAMENTPLAYERID AND TRP.PLAYERID=P.PLAYERID AND T.TEAMID=SS.TEAMID AND SS.GAMESETID=GS.GAMESETID 
AND P.PLAYERID=PB.PLAYERID) AA GROUP BY AA.MATCHID, AA.PLAYERNAME

Comment: Great, if the answer was useful, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the left :)

Answer (score 0):

You must put all columns of the `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` or use aggregate functions on them which compress the results to a single value (like `MIN`, `MAX` or `SUM`).